# How remove backslashes in response for jsonlite in R?

Tags: r, api, plumber

I have the following code for R Plumber API server

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

#' Home endpoint
#' @get /
function(){
  df <- data.table(msg = "Welcome")
  toJSON(df)
}
```

It gives me `["[{\"msg\":\"Welcome\"}]"]` result on API.

How to replace \" on " symbol to make it more human-friendly when working in a browser or Postman? Expected result is "msg":"Welcome".

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but in browsers and Postman I see these \"msg\":\"Welcome\" format. How to make it more human-friendly like "msg":"Welcome". Thanks

Comment: Isn't the `toJSON` done internally? What if you just `return(df)` instead of manually converting it?

Comment: Said differently, `cat(as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(jsonlite::toJSON(data.table(msg = "Welcome")))), "\n")` produces that output on my console, suggesting that your single call to `toJSON` is one of two calls to it.

Comment: @HongOoi, I reopened the question since your dupe-question was about manually editing out backslashes, but this question was ultimately about mis-use of `plumber` mechanisms. `sub` and friends would have ultimately failed in the `plumber` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plumber` already jsonifies it, you are doubling it. Try this:

```r
#' Home endpoint
#' @get /
function(){
  df <- data.table::data.table(msg = "Welcome")
  return(df)
}
```

And then in my console, I ran:

```r
pr <- plumber::plumb("~/StackOverflow/4393334/60918243.R")
pr$run()
# Starting server to listen on port 5225
# Running the swagger UI at http://127.0.0.1:5225/__swagger__/
```

And then on my bash shell:

```sh
$ curl -s localhost:5225
[{"msg":"Welcome"}]
```

Comment: Andrii, I've since reopened the question, please accept this answer when you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Andrii, if the answer addresses your question, please accept it.